# Grunt fails to run on Azure Web Site

Tags: node.js, azure, gruntjs, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I'm trying to build and package my project using Azure's Git deployment.

I have created the following files

- `.deployment`
- `deploy.cmd`
- `Gruntfile.js`
- `package.json`

My `.deployment` file calls `deploy.cmd`. `deploy.cmd` sets up the environment by setting the path to include a checked in copy of Node.js and npm. I can call `npm install` just fine. When I call `grunt`, it seems to execute up to the first standard out message, then it returns and the error return code is set. I don't get any other message than that. Other commands seem to run just fine.

I've tried piping out the STDERR, no luck. I tried running under the Remote Execution console, no luck there. My `Gruntfile.js` runs locally just fine.

Is there some magic sauce that I am missing?

Comment: When you say 'Remote Execution console', what are you referring to? Try launching the Diagnostic Console from the root of the scm service (same host name as the git url). Does it fail there? Can you paste the exact output? Also, if there is a minimal repo you could share, that would be helpful to investigate. It's possible that something is getting blocked by the sandbox.

Comment: @DavidEbbo Yea I'm referring to the Diagnostic Console. It fails there. I just get the C-prompt back. I'm copying files, deleting some of them after copying them (not needed, but part of a Git submodule), running a few templates and parsing environment variables. So pretty standard stuff. What classification of things are blocked by the sandbox?

Comment: Exactly what the sandbox blocks can be subtle. You may also want to look at the Diagnostic Dump (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Investigating-issues#getting-the-diagnostic-dump), which may have more info. If there is any way you can share a minimal repo that would let us see exactly what you're seeing, we should be able to identify what's going on.

Answer (score 15):

This is a bit old, but I will answer it anyway just in case someone comes across this question.

---

First, it is helpful to run grunt with colors disabled, as both the diagnostic console and the deployment logs struggle with the ANSI codes. To do this, run `grunt --no-color`. This should get the STDOUT information back into the Console and into the Deploy log.

Second, I do not recommend using checked-in versions of Node or NPM. Windows Azure already has these build in to the environment, and already is configured for the special temporary paths and cache paths needed for both to execute at their best.

[Project Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) is the deployment engine powering Azure Deployments, but you already know this, since you have a .deployment file. However, the Azure Command Line Tools [`npm install azure-cli --global`] will help you scaffold out some better deployment scripts that will use Azure's pre-installed Node and NPM setup.

```
azure site deploymentscript –-node
```

will get you that base node script.

From there, a few modifications are needed to `deploy.sh` to get it to execute Grunt, reliably. Within `deploy.sh` is a #Deployment section. Replace its contents with the following:

```
# Deployment
# ----------

echo Handling node.js grunt deployment.

# 1. Select node version
selectNodeVersion

# 2. Install npm packages
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE/package.json" ]; then
  eval $NPM_CMD install
  exitWithMessageOnError "npm failed"
fi

# 3. Install bower packages
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE/bower.json" ]; then
  eval $NPM_CMD install bower
  exitWithMessageOnError "installing bower failed"
  ./node_modules/.bin/bower install
  exitWithMessageOnError "bower failed"
fi

# 4. Run grunt
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE/Gruntfile.js" ]; then
  eval $NPM_CMD install grunt-cli
  exitWithMessageOnError "installing grunt failed"
  ./node_modules/.bin/grunt --no-color clean common dist
  exitWithMessageOnError "grunt failed"
fi

# 5. KuduSync to Target
"$KUDU_SYNC_CMD" -v 500 -f "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE/dist" -t "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" -n "$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH" -p "$PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.sh"
exitWithMessageOnError "Kudu Sync to Target failed"
```

This will run `npm install`, followed by `bower install` (if bower.json exists), followed by `grunt clean common dist` (if Gruntfile.js exists), and finally a KuduSync into your `/wwwroot`. (Note: replace 'clean common dist' with whatever Grunt tasks you need to run.)

There are a few other issues you may run in to. I write this up in a [post on my personal blog](http://www.cptloadtest.com/2013/12/03/Git-And-Grunt-Deploy-To-Windows-Azure.aspx), which includes some of the issues you may run into.

Comment: Jay, can this method be used to make Azure Websites run my tests with Karma, right after I deploy with Git, instead of having to run them myself (similar to Travis-CI)?

Comment: Thanks for providing the example.  I also looked through the associated blog post, but did not find anything related to my issue.  I copied the bower and grunt steps into my deploy.sh file.  When I deploy, I get this error message in deployment log 'grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
grunt failed'  Any ideas?

Comment: azure site deploymentscript –-node   generates a deploy.cmd file in my case. Does that mean that this post is now obsolete?!

Comment: @Vaibhav No. You are generating on Windows. It makes bash files on OS X and equivalent Batch files on Windows. These examples just all happen to be in Bash, but can be accomplished in either platform.