# Git: Push only a subdirectory to a remote branch

Tags: git, azure, deployment

I've built a webapp that, using Grunt, creates a `dist` directory which contains all static content. I would like to push only the contents of this directory to a remote branch (`master` on an Azure website). The local branch I'm working on is called `production`.

I've tried this git command:

```
git subtree push --prefix dist azure master
```

This yields the following response:

```
-n 21/      23 (20)
-n 22/      23 (21)
-n 23/      23 (22)
No new revisions were found
```

Comment: Is the content of `dist/` tracked by Git?

Comment: No, it was not. Thank you.

Comment: That's probably why this isn't working, but I urge you to consider whether adding `dist/` to Git and pushing it is the right approach. Git works best when it tracks source code; adding build artefacts causes more problems than it solves IMO. Azure [supports many other deployment methods](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/). Or you can deploy source and [run Grunt directly on Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20353326/354577).